# Submitting serial jobs

Tags: 14.04, scripts

I want to submit a serial job on my ubuntu desktop (PC), not on any HPC cluster. I am working with genomic data and have several runs to do. I want to complete job#1 which creates certain files the job #2 uses this output file and creats another output file. I have to do this for several samples.
I have used HPC cluster (with LSF) before where we can submit a shell script in BSUB and the serial job will take place.
I want to do the same thing and I tried using BSUB in my PC but it doesnot seem to be working (I think bsub is not to be used on pc). I also didnot find any thing similar for a PC ubuntu.
I have seen forums which suggest to submit a run and send it to the background. But, for the easiness I want to submit a job as script. This way I am preparing jobs on queue, not overloading my PC and have to just wait for my final result (not matter couple of days or a week, but its fine).
Can someone give some advise on this matter?

Thanks in advance !